# Are c++ or 64-bit objective C exceptions safely propagated through Swift code?

Tags: c++, swift, exception

I know that c++ exceptions and Swift exceptions (which is essentially syntactic sugar for NSError **) are entirely different.

My question is that, can I expect safe/sane behaviour, when objective-c++ code calls a Swift callback, which in turn calls objective-c++ code, which throws an exception, and the original caller catches said exception. Is this documented somewhere?

In my case, writer of the Swift part would be aware of the situation, so please avoid suggestions on why to avoid this from an architectural standpoint. My question is more like, would Swift objects will be ARC-(auto)released, and would any other runtime-level cleanup which is necessary be done.

Comment: CodaFi: that's my gut feeling as well, but is this documented somewhere? Note that it's still possible to write exception-unsafe code with the c++ abi (and/or in c++), and the Swift standard library is, well, code.

Comment: @CodaFi is incorrect for now.  The exceptions section of the Swift C++ interoperability manifesto sets interoperability of C++ exceptions in invoked(-by-Swift) C++ code as a laudable goal that is not lived up to yet.  https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/docs/CppInteroperabilityManifesto.md#exceptions

Comment: Yeah, I don’t know what was up but that old comment was super wrong. *DO NOT THROW C++ EXCEPTIONS THROUGH SWIFT FRAMES*. Swift has no idea how to emit the right exception propagation or cleanup code for C++, and Swift exceptions (unlike ObjC exceptions) are not ABI compatible with C++ at all - they are a completely different concept. Any exceptions coming from C++ need to be fatal, or be handled in C++.

Answer (score 1):

The Swift C++ interoperability manifesto sets the intended forthcoming expectations regarding C++'s exceptions bubbling up to Swift (but not the other way around yet from Swift code [e.g., callbacks of whichever kind] invoked by C++ where the invoked Swift code threw the exception).
https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/docs/CppInteroperabilityManifesto.md#exceptions

Comment: Additionally, ObjC exceptions should not propagate through Swift frames. That is scary bad undefined behavior. Make sure you wrap anything that can throw across language boundaries to yield the error back to Swift as e.g. an NSError, or kill the process.